# Registry writes only 4 Chars

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

When im try to write a RegEdit Key, he only writes only the first 4 Charaters of the file path.

```
HKEY hKey;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey);
RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Test", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)file, sizeof(file));
RegCloseKey(hKey);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this code because `file` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your `file` is a pointer. `sizeof(file)` is size of pointer in bytes, which is 4 on your platform.

What is `file`? How is it declared? What does it point to? Why are you using `sizeof` on it in order to determine how many bytes to write? If `file` is a pointer to a C-style string, then `sizeof` will not help you to determine the length of that string. You need `strlen` for that.

Comment: file is a char array

Comment: @noaaah an *array* or a *pointer to an array*?

Comment: @noaaah: Unlikely. Apparently `file` is a `char *` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(pointer)` gives 4 on 32 bit systems. Try `string::size` [(online documentation)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) instead.

```
std::string filename ("file.exe");
RegSetValueEx( ..., filename.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

If file is a char array, then...

```
RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Test", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)file, strlen(file) + 1); // API says to include terminating NULL.
```

"The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, in bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx